# Store List in SQLAlchemy scheme

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to store a list in SQLAlchemy.
Best described in the following pseudo-code:

```
species = Species(name="N", indices=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], mass=[0.1])
species.name # N
species.indices # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
species.mass # [0.1]
```

I am using two tables, one called `Species` and one called `SpeciesAttributes`

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, ForeignKey, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Species(Base):
    __tablename__ = "species"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    species_attributes = relationship("SpeciesAttribute")
    
    @property
    def indices(self):
        return [x.value for x in self.species_attributes if x.name == "species"]
    
    @property
    def mass(self):
        return [x.value for x in self.species_attributes if x.name == "mass"]
    
class SpeciesAttribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "species_attributes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Float)
    name = Column(String)
    
    species_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('species.id'))
    species = relationship("Species", back_populates='species_attributes')
```

This allows me to do

```
sp = Species(name="N")
for x in range(5):
    SpeciesAttribute(species=sp, value=x, name="species")
SpeciesAttribute(species=sp, value=0.5, name="mass")
print(species.indices)
```

but I would like to be able to do

```
sp = Species(name="N", indices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], mass=[0.5])
ses.add(sp)
ses.commit()
```

Can this be done with SQLAlchemy? I have looked into mappings and composites which in some way seem to be close to what I am looking for but I could not translate them to the functionality I am looking for. Could I somehow define a custom Column which functions as the property `setter` and `getter` ?

Comment: Do you want to store actual lists in the database (so you have only one table and model), or you want to be able to pass raw values and  have SQLAlchemy automatically convert to and from `SpeciesAttribute` instances (so two tables and models as in the question)?  If the latter,  will `SpeciesAttributes` instances ever be exposed in your code or will the be purely implementation details of `Species`?

Comment: The `SpeciesAttribute` will not be used outside. But I want to be able to expand the attributes, which is why I don't want to use `ARRAY`. I'll probably save the attributes as a JSON string in the database, which does not require db migrations when expanding and is faster to query.

Comment: I was thinking if you wanted the child table you could use a [custom collection class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/collections.html#custom-collection-implementations), but JSON sounds simpler for what you want.